# Python 3: clean example for inheritance & abstract methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

The actual code is vastly different and on a whole different topic, but I felt that this small example might be better since my problem is understanding the key concepts for complex inheritance scenarios (and not my specific domain).

Let's consider we have a basic `Entity` class:

```
from enum import Enum
from abc import abstractmethod

class Condition(Enum):
    ALIVE = 1
    DEAD = 2
    UNDEAD = 3

class Entity(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.condition = Condition.ALIVE
        self.position = 0
        self.hitpoints = 100

    def move(self):
        self.position += 1

    def changeHitpoints(self, amount):
        self.hitpoints += amount

    @abstractmethod
    def attack(self, otherEntity):
        pass
```

This is a base class other concrete entities inherit from and `attack()` has to be abstract, since every entity should implement its own style of attack method.

Now we could implement some entities:

```
class Orc(Entity):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hitpoints = 150
        self.damage = 10

    def attack(self, otherEntity : Entity):
        otherEntity.changeHitpoints(-self.damage)

class Human(Entity):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.damage = 8

    def attack(self, otherEntity : Entity):
        otherEntity.changeHitpoints(-self.damage)

class Undead(Entity):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.condition = Condition.UNDEAD
        self.damage = 5

    def attack(self, otherEntity : Entity):
        # harm enemy
        otherEntity.changeHitpoints(-self.damage)
        # heal yourself
        self.changeHitpoints(1)
```

This works fine. However, I am struggling to figure out a good solution ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)-style) for implementing "abilities" and other stuff.

For example, if `Orc` and `Human` should not only move, but also be able to jump, it would be interesting to have something like:

```
class CanJump(Entity):

    def jump(self):
        self.position += 2

class Orc(Entity, CanJump):
    (...)

class Human(Entity, CanJump):
    (...)
```

This introduces two problems. (1) we need access to `self.position` in `CanJump`, thus we have to inherit from `Entity`?! If we do so, we have to implement the abstract method `attack()` in class `CanJump`. This does not make sense, since `CanJump` should just give entities the ability of a new type of movement. (2) in the future we might want to implement for example a decorator that checks if the condition of an entity is `Condition.DEAD` before executing `move()`, `attack()`, ... This also means `CanJump` needs access to `self.condition`.

What would be a clean solution for this type of problems?

What if there is a need for further subclassing? E.g. we might be interested in creating an `UndeadHuman` like `class UndeadHuman(Undead, Human)`. Due to the linearization (`Undead` first in order) it should have the `attack` behavior of an `Undead` but it also needs the `CanJump` from a `Human`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [W]e need access to self.position in CanJump, thus we have to inherit from Entity?!

No, you don't. You can treat `CanJump` as a *mix-in class*, that simply adds functionality. Any classes that subclass `CanJump` are expected to have a `position` attribute. And the `CanJump` class itself, doesn't need to inherit from `Entity`. So doing:

```
class CanJump:
    def jump(self):
        self.position += 2
```

Would be perfectly fine. You can then do:

```
class Orc(Entity, CanJump):
    (...)

class Human(Entity, CanJump):
    (...)
```

Here is a complete example that demonstrates the above would work:

```
from abc import abstractmethod


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0 

    @abstractmethod
    def m(self):
        pass


class C:
    def c(self):
        self.a += 1


class B(A, C):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def m(self):
        print('method in B')


b = B()
print(b.a) # 0
b.c()
print(b.a) # 1
b.m() # method in B
```

You see, you can use currently non-existent attributes in a method implementation. The attributes just need to exist when the method is called. And letting subclasses of `CanJump` implement the needed attributes works well.

If you want to force users of your class to defined certain attributes, you can use a meta-class. Rather than repeating information, I'll point you to [@kindall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046369/enforcing-class-variables-in-a-subclass/22047600#22047600), which deals with this rather elegantly.

Comment: This is an interesting concept. Is this a Python / duck-typing related feature? I have never seen *mix-in* classes before. Is there a way to prevent `CanJump` from being instantiated directly? One might do this by accident and then `self.position += 2` would have an unresolved reference. Additionally, I am wondering if we could type hint attributes somehow?

Comment: @daniel451 Not at all, many other languages support mix-in classes. They may be called by different names however, such as traits in PHP. Although it's a bit more sticky to implement in statically-typed languages. I'll update with an example addressing your other concerns in a bit.

Comment: @daniel451 it's a common technique for languages with multiple inheritance. You can do the same thing in Java now with interfaces that provide default methods.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to model this not via inheritance, but composition.

You can have an `Entity` class that gets used for every creature and a separate `RaceModifier` class that sets the relevant constants/adjustments and abilities. Then each creature can have a list of these to model the races in game, for example:

```
class RaceModifier:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.abilities = []

class Orc(RaceModifier):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.extra_hit_points = 50
        self.extra_damage = 2
        self.abilities = [JUMPING]

class Undead(RaceModifier):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.abilities = [REGEN_ON_ATTACK]

class Entity:
    ...
    def has_ability(self, ability): # ability = JUMPING etc
        for race in self.race_modifiers:
            if ability in race.abilities:
                return True
        for eq in self.equipment: # wearing a ring of jumping ? :)
            if ability in eq.abilities:
                return True
        return False
```

Comment: This is also an interesting concept. Do you have some more (good) examples for *composition* in Python?

Comment: `abilities` should probably be a `dict`, so that you can more quickly check for an appropriate ability.